# What could cause this drop in photo quality?

Tags: camera, huawei-u8850

The recent photos I've tried to take with my phone look like the one on left compared to older photos that look like the one on the right.

[image: new photo] 
[image: old photo]

I haven't (knowingly) changed any of the phone settings, and as far as I can see I should be taking the highest quality<sup>*</sup>/resolution photos possible.

But as you can see all the newer photos are coming out as though they are taken through a rain storm or on a very cloudy day (which isn't the case). Even photos taken indoors with the flash are very poor quality - so poor I deleted them as they were useless for recording the event I was at.

Is this a physical problem with the lens or something in the software I can improve?

<sup>*</sup> By "quality" I mean lowest compression etc. not a comment on the artistic quality (or otherwise) of the photos.

Comment: Give a try by playing with different camera settings. Or reset the settings to default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a physical problem with the camera - either the lens or (more likely) the glass that covers the lens.

On a close inspection of the camera I can see a lot (for the small area) of dark specks on the *inside* of the outermost lens element.

I don't know what's caused this, but it's this that's causing the reduction in quality of the images.